# Kotlin, выборка строк из массива в зависимости от значений в других строках

Tags: парсер, kotlin

Есть такие входные данные

```
/u01/app/oracle:
        dev             = /dev/oralv
        vfs             = jfs2
        log             = /dev/sideloglv
        mount           = false
        check           = false
        type            = side
        options         = rw
        account         = false

/opt/safewatch:
        dev             = /dev/safewatchlv
        vfs             = jfs2
        log             = /dev/sideloglv
        mount           = false
        check           = false
        type            = side
        options         = rw
        account         = false

/forbackup:
        dev             = /dev/fslv00
        vfs             = jfs2
        log             = /dev/sideloglv
        mount           = false
        check           = false
        options         = rw
        account         = false

/proc:
        dev       = /proc
        vol       = "/proc"
        mount     = true
        check     = false
        free      = false
        vfs       = procfs
```

Собственно задача получить в итоге список из всех точек монтирования, где `vfs = jfs2` (т.е. для данного списка отбросить `/proc`)

Сейчас решаю таким образом (`validFs` - это `Set` с теми `vfs`, которые оставляем)

```
val out = HashSet<String>()
var current = ""
inputStrings
        .forEach {
            when {
                it[0] == '/'                            -> current = it.trimEnd(':')
                it.startsWith("vfs")
                && it.substringAfter('=').trimStart() in validFs -> out.add(current)
            }
        }
return out
```

Но конструкция сия вызывает во мне противоречивые чувства. Может данная задача решается как-то проще и изящнее, но я просто об этом не знаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так.

```
return inputStrings
    .filter{ it.startsWith("/") || it.contains(" vfs ") }
    .mapIndexed{ index, value -> Pair(index / 2, value) }
    .groupBy{ it.first }
    .filter{ it.value[1].second.substringAfterLast(" ") in validFs }
    .map{ it.value[0].second.trimEnd(':') }
```

Функциональнее, но не факт, что лучше.